# Eclipse line wrapping for XHTML files?

Tags: eclipse, xhtml

I have set the line wrapping as 180 and i realized that Eclipse is only applying that to Java source codes, how do i get that to apply to my XHTML codes as well?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set the desired line width under **HTML files:** *Preferences → Web → HTML Files → Editor*

[image]

Comment: Great - which setting was it?

Comment: It was placed under the HTML editor, and modifying the line width for that solves it.